# I can't understand where the minus sign in the second equation is coming from

Tags: general-relativity

$R_{\mu v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\lambda}} \Gamma_{\mu v}^{\lambda}+\Gamma_{\mu \lambda}^{\eta} \Gamma_{v \eta}^{\lambda}$

equation (2) after the multiplication of the meteric tensor

$g^{\nu\sigma}R_{\mu v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\lambda}} g^{\sigma\beta}\Gamma_{\mu \beta}^{\lambda}-g^{\alpha \beta} \Gamma_{\alpha \lambda}^{\sigma} \Gamma_{\beta \mu}^{\lambda}$

Answer (score 2):

Metric compatibility
$$
\nabla_\lambda g_{\mu\nu} =\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}+ g_{\alpha\nu}{\Gamma^\alpha}_{\mu\lambda}+ g_{\mu\alpha}{\Gamma^\alpha}_{\nu\lambda}=0. $$